# Employer did not call for interview

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I am applying for an entry level position with a company.
On the day that I emailed my resume I got an immediate response from the hiring manager asking if we could talk that very day.
However after they confirmed the time tomorrow (yesterday now), they did not call me all day. Before the interview I sent a note asking if we could push the interview time five or ten minutes later. I sent a follow up email about 30 minutes after the call was supposed to start. I’m worried that my first email was a problem but feel it shouldn’t be given that I didn’t say I wouldn’t be available at the original time only asking if it would be possible to slightly move it?

My question is what should I do next? 
I don’t want to send another followup email because this would be third email in a row (including the two I mentioned above). Should I try once to call the company phone number? (The interviewer did not provide their phone number)

Comment: Wait a couple of days, then time for another email. Wait a couple of days, then it's time to call them.

Comment: see also: [Should I send a second follow-up email to schedule an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61081/should-i-send-a-second-follow-up-email-to-schedule-an-interview)

Comment: Is it possible that they wanted you to initiate the call?

Comment: @Steve-o169 hmm I feel like that’s unlikely? As the manager never provided their number to me but did ask for mine

Comment: I guess I’m also just confused because this usually happens because  they found another candidate but it’s literally in under less than 12 hours from when they confirmed they would call...haha

Comment: @Steve-o169 Not if they didn't provide a number to call. Oversight? Overlooked? or miscommunication?